# vue-router:how to not `saveScrollPosition`

Tags: javascript, vue-router

In my case, I have used `vue` and `vue-router`. I have fould a problem that somewhat the `saveScrollPostion` property can **not** work well.

This is my codes:

`router.js`

```
export default router => {
"use strict"
router.map({
    //'/': {
    //    component: null
    //},
    '/blogs': {
        component: require('./views/ArticleListPage.vue'),
        subRoutes: {
            '/': {
                component: require('./components/ArticleList/ArticleListSection.vue'),
            },
            '/tag/:name': {
                component: require('./components/ArticleList/ArticleListSection.vue'),
                name: 'tag'
            },
            '/classification/:name': {
                component: require('./components/ArticleList/ArticleListSection.vue'),
                name: 'classification'
            }
        }
    },
    '/projects': {
        component: require('./views/ProjectPage.vue')
    },
    '/about': {
        component: require('./views/AboutPage.vue')
    },
    '/p/:id': {
        component: require('./views/ArticlePage.vue')
    },
    '*': {
        component: require('./views/NotFound.vue')
    }
});

router.beforeEach(()=>{

});
```

In `index.js`, there are two settings in the `Router` instance:

```
const router = new Router({
    history: true,
    saveScrollPosition: false
});
```

**The problem is:**  if going to any of the `/p/:id` route and scrolling the page down, you will find the previous page also scrolled after going back.

I have read [vue-router](http://router.vuejs.org/en/options.html) documentation, it says the saveScrollPostion

> might not work as expected if your  has transition effects.

When deleting the setting, or just changing the `saveScrollPosition` to false, the problem is still there.

I guess it is the `router.map` method I wrote that causes the wrong result.

I also wonder whether there is any bug in my project codes instead of the `vue-router` settings that leads to this problem.

Further more, I haven't written any `transition` settings between route transitions.

Thank all of you for answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

try to watch for $route property of Vue, e.g:

```
watch: {
    $route: function() {
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
}
```